# How do I mount a Vue 3 CLI project like codepen

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vue-cli, vuejs3

I have written a working pen [here](https://codepen.io/mongolsteppe/pen/jOMqwKR).

I'm trying to replicate the same app within a vue-cli project. Everything is on default settings (vue3 preview), except for these 2 files:

**main.js**

```js
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import BoostApp from './App.vue'
    
createApp(BoostApp).mount('#box')
```

**App.vue**

```html
<template>
  <div id="box" class="demo">
    <h1>
      Compound vault
      <br />
    </h1>
    <span>
    Deposit
    <input type="number" min="0" v-model="deposit" style="width:6em" /> USD (in stablecoins)
    </span>
    <br />
    <br />CRV needed for 2.5x boost:
    <br />
    {{Math.ceil(deposit/CRVneeded*100)/100}} CRV for 4 years
  </div>
</template>
```

```js
<script>
  export default {
    name: "BoostApp",
    data() {
      return {
        deposit: 10,
        CRVneeded: 2.12
      };
    }
  };
</script>
<style>
</style>
```

It builds fine with 'npm run serve', but when I visit http://localhost:8080/ I just get a blank screen.

Where am I going wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The app mounts to the div in *index.html*, not the one in *App.vue*.  So if you haven't renamed the div `id` to `box` in *index.html*, this is why.

You could also change this back to `#app` instead (recommended):

```html
createApp(BoostApp).mount('#app')
```